# PHP - Upload File Script in a For Loop

Tags: php, html, image, loops, upload

So I have this form in a for loop which submits to itself and gets images uploaded by users, the form code:

```
    for ($x=1; $x<=10; $x++)
    {
    echo "<form method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>";

    echo "
    <label for='file'>Image:</label>
    <input type='file' name='file'><br>
    <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Upload Image'>
    <br>";

    include ('lib/upload.php');
    }
```

the form will then call a script named "upload.php" which contains these codes:

```
    <?php
     if (isset($_POST['submit']))
     {
        $allowedext=array("gif", "png", "jpeg", "jpg");
        $tmp=explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
        $ext=end($tmp);

        if (
        (($_FILES["file"]["type"]=="image/gif") ||
        ($_FILES["file"]["type"]=="image/jpeg") ||
        ($_FILES["file"]["type"]=="image/jpg") ||
        ($_FILES["file"]["type"]=="image/pjpeg") ||
        ($_FILES["file"]["type"]=="image/png") ||
        ($_FILES["file"]["type"]=="image/x-png")) &&
        ($_FILES["file"]["size"]<=3145728) && in_array($ext, $allowedext)
        )
        {
            if ($_FILES["file"]["error"]>0)
            {
                echo "<br>Error: ".$_FILES["file"]["error"]."<br>";
            }
            else
            {
                if (file_exists("upload/".$_FILES["file"]["name"]))
                {
                    echo "<br><p style='color: #ff0000;'>".$_FILES["file"]["name"]." already exists.</p><br>";
                }
                else
                {
                    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "upload/".$_FILES["file"]["name"]);
                    $x="upload/".$_FILES["file"]["name"];

                    echo "<br><img src='$x' width='320px' height='240px'><br>";
                }
            }
        }
        else if ($_FILES["file"]["size"]>3145728)
        {
            echo "<br><p style='color: #ff0000;'>File too large</p><br>";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "<br><p style='color:#ff0000;'>Invalid file</p><br>";
        }
     }
    ?>
```

So my problem is, everytime I upload an image, the error "Invalid File" comes up even though I'm pretty sure I uploaded a valid file. This works if I loop the form once, like this:

```
    for ($x=1; $x<=1; $x++)
    {
        \\code
    }
```

any ideas what the problem could be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Found something wrong in you code,also something wrong in with the process 
of multiple file upload:

in you first code fragment there have a for loop,and this code is wrong 
include ('lib/upload.php'); i don't know why no error occur for you,
but you should use include_onde instead include.this is what you code error.

with multiple file upload you needn't create multiple form,you should create a form like this:

```
<form>
   <input type='file' name='upload_file[]' />
   <input type='file' name='upload_file[]' />
   <input type='file' name='upload_file[]' />
   <input type='file' name='upload_file[]' />
</form>
```

and in you php something like this:

```
foreach ($_FILES as $key => $value)
{

    foreach($value as $k=>$v)
    {
           if($k !== "error")
           {
              $_FILES[$key][$k] = array_filter($v);
           }                 
     }
}
$name = $_FILES['upload_file']['name'];
if(empty($name))
{
  //do whatever you want to tell user no file uploaded
}
```

above code is for remove empty upload file form $_FILES;

then

```
$tmp_name=$_FILES['upload_file']['tmp_name'];
$size=$_FILES['upload_file']['size'];
$error=$_FILES['upload_file']['error'];
$filepath = "/usr/www/project/image/";
$ext="get ext by yourself";//like ".jpg" 
foreach($name as $key=>$value)
{
  move_uploaded_file($tmp_name["{$key}"], $filepath.$value.$ext);
  //do other thing here one by one.
 }
```

enjoy youself..

Answer (score 0):

you lost a form in your code.

insert `echo '&lt;/form&gt;';` in your code.

introduce you a website:
http://www.w3schools.com/PHP/php_file_upload.asp

enjoy your learning time.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add `</form>` at the end of for loop.

```
for ($x=1; $x<=10; $x++)
    {
    echo "<form method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>";

    echo "
    <label for='file'>Image:</label>
    <input type='file' name='file'><br>
    <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Upload Image'>
    <br></form>"; //end form here

    include ('lib/upload.php');
    }
```

Your form is not closing so creating problem with another forms.
But it get closed then all forms will work fine.